# Calculate extrinsincs root

Tags: extrinsic

I'm trying to calculate extrinsic root from the given extrinsics in the block and compare it with extrinsics root in the header. The result is not the same.

Here is an example for block `10030907` in polkadot

```
BlakeTwo256::ordered_trie_root(
        block
            .block
            .extrinsics
            .into_iter()
            .map(|ext| ext.0)
            .collect(),
        sp_runtime::StateVersion::V0,
    );
```

Result: `0xcc69903a7b42a3bf3a12d2e4d7be2b8dc16f8d7d620f8f77cb3cfbfafdf25197`

Expected(in the header): `0x13ae7177c2e2dd759ab8b0a85859fdcf0c4b8b23f5f1ad94d76ba740abaea711`

I'm using custom OpaqueExtrinsic that makes the inner Vec public and rest all remains same as the `sp_runtime::OpaqueExtrinsic`

Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the encoded extrinsics, so the following should do it:

```
BlakeTwo256::ordered_trie_root(
   block
       .block
       .extrinsics
       .iter()
       .map(Encode::encode)
       .collect(),
   sp_runtime::StateVersion::V0,
);
```